# File Filter for FileSystemWatcher()

Tags: c#, filter, filenames

I am trying to figure out, how to watch only certain way of files:
e.g.

1. Folder will populate files with the same name, but different extension (.zip, .another)
2. The file will have a certain name e.g. ASK_QUESTION_VERSION_XXXXXXX.zip, where the XXXXXX will change.
3. Since the folder will have different files populated e.g. DIFFERENT_FILE_XXXXXX.zip, with similar naming, I would only want to watch for the first files being placed.

How can I filter this here? Here is a look at the code:

```
 public void watch(List<string> servicesInvolved, int timeout)
    {
        watcher.Path = sourcePath;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName
                               | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        // The below did not work, e.g. compilation errors, could not add two filters. 
        //watcher.Filter.Add("*.zip");
        //watcher.Filters.Add("FileName*");

        watcher.Created += (sender, e) => OnChanged(sender, e,  servicesInvolved, timeout);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    }
```

Comment: `Filter = "ASK_QUESTION_VERSION_*.zip"` ?

Comment: Additionally, obviously you can do the filtering in code, trigger on every file (or at least the best filter you can actually get working), and then just check the filenames yourself.

Comment: _" I would only want to watch for the first files being placed"_ - so if `ASK_QUESTION_VERSION_1.zip` gets placed, you want to be notified, but if after that a `DIFFERENT_FILE_2.zip`, you don't want to be notified, but you do want to be notified of `ASK_QUESTION_VERSION_2.zip` again? So your filter actually should be ``ASK_QUESTION_VERSION_*.zip`` as @Lasse indicates? Or do you want to be notified of one file only?

Comment: If you need filtering that can't be handled by wildcards, you can check the path or attributes inside the event handler

Comment: @CodeCaster for some reason this solution didn't come up in my head. I will try it, but this is exactly what I wanted to have. I thought that if indicating * as this, then it would only focus on one Character, but the option ASK_QUESTION_VERSION_245454HotFix.zip should be picked up as well.

Comment: In Windows filename wildcards * means any number of characters. ? Means one character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somehow a simple answer as per @CodeCaster   `watcher.Filter = MyFolder*Name*.zip;`